# C# MQSeries put method issue

Tags: c#, format, hex, ibm-mq

I have developed a MQRC client based on the standard description found in a different forum.

```
mqMessage = new MQMessage();
//mqMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
mqMessage.WriteString(message);
//mqMessage.Encoding = 546;
//mqMessage.CharacterSet = 1208;

mqPutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();

//putting the message into the mqQueue
mqQueue.Put(mqMessage, mqPutMessageOptions);
```

The code listed above works fine and I can send the messge to the approrpiate queue.
But in the queue the message contains a Hex value 00 between every character from the source message. I also have tried to change encoding and character set but it did not have any effect of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using `WriteString` method to write the message body. `WriteString` method uses code page 1200. Each character is represented by 2 bytes, of which first byte will be 0x00. You can choose the `WriteUTF` method instead as this method writes message body using UTF8.

FYI: If you are using `WriteString` method, then make sure you use `ReadString` method for reading message body. Similarly if you write using `WriteUTF`, then use `ReadUTF` to read message body.